# Non-Greek myths set in a wedding

Tags: comparative

There are a many Greek myths that are set in a wedding, like Thetis wedding as the origin of the Trojan War (see also Harmonia's necklace and Orion's earthborn myth). Are there other tales in major mythologies that are set in a wedding? I am looking for myths that are set in a wedding and not origin myths of wedding rituals per se.

Comment: The Kalevala describes a wedding, and how the traditional family roles are connected to it, in chapters 20 to 24. This is, IMO, the most enjoyable part of the Kalevala. I hesitate in making this answer though, because the wedding proper probably doesn't count as mythology. The identity of the husband, and the impossible tasks that he has to perform as dowry, as described in the chapters before, those do count as mythology, but that is not what you're asking for.

Answer (score 4):

There is a pretty famous Norse myth in which Thor has his hammer stolen by a giant, Thrym. The giant says he will only let Thor have the hammer back if Freyja, the goddess of beauty and fertility, will marry him. Freyja says no way (understandable) and Loki convinces Thor to dress up as a bride, and then go and pretend to be Freyja at the wedding. The two of them go to meet Thrym, and they have a banquet. As soon as Thor gets a sight of his hammer, which is brought out at the end of the feast as a wedding present, Thor grabs it and kills all the giants. The end.
[Here's a link where you can read the myth for yourself](https://norse-mythology.org/tales/thor-the-transvestite/)

Answer (score 0):

In Christian mythology, in [John 2:1–11](https://bible.oremus.org/?passage=John%202:1%E2%80%9311&version=nrsv), at the [Wedding at Cana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wedding_at_Cana), Jesus turns water into wine.